# showHide doesn't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, internet-explorer-9

Does anyone know why the script below doesn't work in IE9? It works in other newer browsers. 
Instead op showing a pop up (" class="more">), it removes the  everytime you click one a product.

This is the code in head:

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function cancelBubble(e) {
     var evt = e ? e:window.event;
     if (evt.stopPropagation)    evt.stopPropagation();
     if (evt.cancelBubble!=null) evt.cancelBubble = true;
    }

    function showHide(shID) {
    if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
        if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
            document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This is a part of the code in body:

```
    <div class="main" style="position:relative;">
    <form name="form1" id="form1">
      <input type="hidden" name="productid" />
      <input type="hidden" name="command" />
    </form>
    <h1>Webshop</h1>
    <div style="margin: 1.5em -5px -20px -5px;">
      <a href="#" id="example-show" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">
      <div class="shopproduct" align="center">
      <div style="height:175px; vertical-align:bottom; display:table-cell;"><img style="max-height:175px; max-width: 175px;" src="images/example.png" /></div>
      <div style="font-size:1em; line-height:1.8em"><b>
        Example name 1
        </b><br />
        <div style="font-size:0.8em; line-height:1.2em; height:2.4em;">
          Short description example 1
          ...</div>
      </div>
      <div style="line-height:2em"><strong>&euro;
        9,50
        </strong></div>
      <div id="example" class="more" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">
      <div onclick="cancelBubble(event);" style="position: absolute; background:#FFF; 
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        width:400px;  /* adjust as per your needs */
        height:400px;   /* adjust as per your needs */
        margin-left:-200px;   /* negative half of width above */
        margin-top:-200px;   /* negative half of height above */
    z-index: 9002;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
      Short description example 1
      <a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide this content</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
</a>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 20px; width: 250px; line-height:2em;" align="right"><a href="shoppingcart.php">Artikelen in winkelwagen -
  0
  </a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT 12-11-2014: POSTED HTML INSTEAD OF PHP/MYSQL

Comment: Please post actual HTML, not stuff from the server.

Comment: How do you mean, Rob?

Comment: Presumably `<? $result=mysql_query("select * from products"); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){$prijs=$row['price'];?>` generates some HTML.

Comment: I've edited the first post so it's all HTML/CSS. Hope somebody can help me.